# Clarification on Exception handling

Tags: .net, winforms, exception

Its my understanding that when an `Exception` is thrown it will bubble up the call stack until it is handled (within a try/catch block) and if this never happens the exception will eventually go so far that it will reach Program.Main() and if still not handled is deemed an 'Unhandled Exception' by the runtime.

Is this correct?  I've searched high and low and cannot find any information which agrees with this?  Any inaccuracies in what I've said?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Its my understanding that when an Exception is thrown it will bubble up the call stack until it is handled (within a try/catch block) and if this never happens the exception will eventually go so far that it will reach Program.Main() and if still not handled is deemed an 'Unhandled Exception' by the runtime.

Your description, though not inaccurate per se, is extremely incomplete; you do not describe what happens for cases with:

- finally blocks
- fault blocks
- catch blocks with filters

Note that the last two CLR features are not exposed by the C# language, but they still exist.

The control flow for those three cases plus ordinary catch blocks can be quite complex.

If you want a more complete understanding of how this works, I recommend a thorough and close reading of Christopher Brumme's detailed article on the subject:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/10/01/51524.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's about correct. And that's why exception handling is important.

Something interesting to read about exceptions:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx

Comment: The best source i know is the CLI specification. A bit dry to read though.  
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm

Comment: This is incorrect. That is *not* why exception handling is important. You should not handle exceptions that you can't do anything about. And most of the time, if you can do something about the exception, that's an indication that you're using it for flow control, which you shouldn't be doing in the first place. Exceptions should be reserved for truly *exceptional* conditions, which you likely won't be *able* to handle, and *should* bubble up even to crash the program if necessary.

Comment: I did not state how to handle the exceptions. You should certainly not catch all exceptions. See the link i added.

Comment: @Cody True, you shouldn't use exception handling for flow control and you shouldn't catch exceptions you aren't going to do *anything* about. However, you may want different layers/classes of your program to handle their own exceptions and possibly wrap them before throwing up to a higher level custom handler.

Comment: @El Ronnoco: Perhaps, but the risk of doing so is that you lose valuable call stack information. Each time you catch and rethrow an exception, the stack is unwound by the time the catch clause is executed. It depends on the design of your class library, I suppose, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Cody: You should attach the original exception as an InnerException to the new exception so that the detail is available to the caller. Also, exceptions aren't just for exceptional conditions. They can be for usage errors, program errors, or system failures.

Comment: @Road: That's far from a perfect solution. And there's absolutely no reason to catch and rethrow a bundled exception in the first place, unless you're implementing some kind of custom exception logging functionality. As for your argument that exceptions are not just for exceptional conditions...huh? Yeah, I think "usage errors, program errors, and system failures" *all* qualify as "exceptional conditions". What do you call those things collectively? The point is, exceptions should be things that are *uncommon* and *unusual*. Unless you have a very good reason to catch an exception, don't.

Comment: @Cody: As an example, imagine that your library implements user details storage as a text file. Your callers have no interest in your implementation. So you would want to catch the "File not found" exception and throw instead a custom "User details not found" exception.

Comment: @Cody: Good reasons to catch and re-throw include restoring a class to a safe state after an exception, improving on an exception produced by Microsoft libraries or third-party code, and hiding implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

> Its my understanding that when an Exception is thrown it will bubble up the call stack until it is handled (within a try/catch block) and if this never happens the exception will eventually go so far that it will reach Program.Main() and if still not handled is deemed an 'Unhandled Exception' by the runtime.

In addition to handling an exception within a `catch` block, an exception will not reach `Program.Main()` under the following conditions (and excluding things like power outages, etc.)

- If a `finally` block throws an exception, then the original exception will no longer be propogated.
- If the exception is thrown by a thread other than the main thread, then it will become an "unhandled exception" without reaching `Program.Main()`. (In the newer versions of the .NET runtime.)